# Ruby on Rails link middle click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple links in my project for example:

_index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to('New Project', new_project_path, :remote => true) if Project.create_authorized? %>
```

controller:

```
def new
  @project = Account.root_account.nil? ? Project.new : Account.root_account.projects.new
end
```

new.js.erb:

```
$("#right-panel").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'projects/form', :locals => {:project => @project}) ) -%>");
```

My problem is that when I am doing mouse middle click(I mean, I want to open a new tab) on the link then it raises a error as:

> Template is missing Missing template projects/new, application/new
>   with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
>   :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :arb]}. Searched in: *
>   "/home/raj/workspace/papayaheaderlabs.banana/app/views" *
>   "/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@banana/gems/doorkeeper-2.2.1/app/views"
>   * "/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@banana/bundler/gems/activeadmin-655e2be7a351/app/views"
>   * "/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@banana/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"

Plese help how to solve this issue

Comment: according to the error, the request being made is of `html` format as shown in error `:formats=>[:html]` and so it is searching for `new.html.erb` file. while you are expecting `js` request. though i think you add the `remote: true` correctly which should go with `js` request. i would suggest to please see if ajax request is being made or not.

Comment: It might pay to check for invalid html or js errors, too...

Comment: I believe you actually want to duplicate the current tab and execute the same js `new.js.erb` in the duplicated tab right ? The problem there is that middle-mouse click is probably browser-specific and users can always override the default behavior through config or plugins. So you should just create a `new.html.erb` as S. Tulentsev suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long googling I found the only one relevant answer to my question i.e.
I have only to do one thing i.e. disable middle click and right button click on the link. Since, I have the link which is actually sending js(java-script) request and render js.erb page(which is available).But in case of right click or middle click on the link it sends html request and there is no page found for html.erb, that's why it raises error as "Template is missing".

So, only option is:  disable middle click and right button click

Comment: Could you share how you disabled the middle/right click?

Answer (score 2):

To fix your error, you have to provide the missing template. In this case, it seems to be `views/projects/new.html.erb`.

Partial update, provided by `new.js.erb` (which is invoked by `remote: true`) doesn't make sense in the context of a new page. There's no existing page to change part of! (particularly, there would be no `#right-panel`)

So you must render a full page here, complete with footer, header navigation, all that stuff.

Answer (score -2):

Your Link looks correct please check if you have added

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

in the application.js file

If jquery_ujs is not included :remote => true will not work.
And the request is going as html and it is search for the new.html.erb template

Comment: This is not what question is about.

Comment: This is not relevant answer bro, my question is how to handle this "template is missing error" so that is would not through error message

Comment: My point is , if the remote => true is not working it will search for new.html.erb template , so make sure that remote true is working and it will respond to new.js.erb and you will not get "template missing error"

Comment: @Pushpalata: it is working. Just not on the blank page.

Comment: Pushpalata mam its working fine, but in case of middle click on the link  for new tab open, its raise error: "template is missing"